# Installing Microsoft Office using Wine

Tags: linux, ms-office, wine

Hey I'm trying to install Microsoft Office using linux and wine but everytime I run the setup application I get this error:

> Setup cannot find the required setup controller file. Either there was
>   a network error, an error reading from the CD, DVD, or other
>   installation media, or a problem with the package you downloaded.

I'm not sure what I should do.

Comment: Wine is good but not that good to be without bugs. I just recommend you to use Libre Office, it is a good office suite .

Comment: The thing with Libre office is it's alignment are wrong when someone else opens a document in word they have different alignment and my texts are all over the place.

Comment: Is it a docx document ? Try to import the document to google docs and export it to .doc/.odt ..You still have the choice to use office online https://office.live.com/start/Word.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of office do you try to install? Probably you can try to install other version, that works better with wine. I hope this link will help you - https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=31
it is list of versions of Microsoft office and their perfomance under wine.

Comment: I'm installing office 2007.